# Finding Distinct combinations + additional fields

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct-values

I want to find out all instances where a UniqueID matches to a given email, and see each transaction and transaction type for each distinct email/ID combination.

Essentially: Distinct(Primaryemail, UserId) + transaction, transaction type.

Hoping to return something along the lines of:

| [PrimaryEmail] | [UserId] | [Transaction] | [TransactionType] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com | 12345 | 210420-1 | 2 |
| abc@gmail.com | 67890 | 210421-1 | 3 |

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?